# SearchView in Action bar with customize search button

Tags: android, searchview

In the menu, I have search view. when I clicked search in menu search view should expand with customized search button.like below image currently it is opening like normal search

[image]

I want to change the default submit button with custom button

```
 SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
 searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Show code for what you have already tried.

Comment: Don't post it in comment, edit your answer above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ImageView b = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_go_btn);
    b.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_button_drawable);
```

try this one to change default search submit button

Comment: yes i have tried this i want to add button.but this will also help thanks